# Can I use the Castle Logging facility during registration phase?

Tags: logging, castle-windsor

I am using the Castle Windsor logging facility and it's working great.  I have an installer which registers an interceptor plus a facility to hook up to events so that I can keep most of my code blissfully unaware of both Castle and log4net.

Most of my registration happens in code, but for the logging I am hooking it up in the web.config (which installs first) like this:

```
<castle>        
    <facilities>
         <facility id="logging"
              type="Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility, Castle.Facilities.Logging" loggingApi="log4net" />
    </facilities>
    <installers>
        <install type="MyProject.LoggerInstaller,MyProject" />
    </installers>
</castle>
```

The reason is that I don't have to include this config section when I go to production.  It also means I can very easily switch from log4net to nlog to whatever else we might want on the fly.  And means that none of my components have to directly reference log4net.

The problem I am having is that I would like to use some logging during the registration phase itself.  I'm doing this because the registration is a little complex and I want to be able to easily keep an eye on what's going on and how long it's taking.  (Mainly because I have a plugin type system.)

In my LoggerInstaller I am trying to resolve ILoggerFactory so that I can create a logger and hook up some events for it in my utility object.  But this fails with this:

```
ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Castle.Core.Logging.ILoggerFactory was found
```

From digging around the Castle source I *think* that all installers are installed before any facilities, so it appears that the facility hasn't been initialised inside my installer.  If I create a 2nd installer just to hook up the events so that it doesn't happen via the XML configuration then it works, but I would like everything log related together - and it doesn't make sense to hook up events if logging isn't available.  (And I'd have to somehow figure out if logging was enabled..??)

Ideally I would like to register the Castle Logging facility from my installer but I don't know how to wrap up its configurable elements.  (Or whether I want to.)

Is there an easier way?  I suspect I'm not doing something that is normally a great idea as I know I shouldn't really resolve in the registration phase.  But I think installation is complex enough to warrant a little logging.

Has anyone else done this kind of thing before?  Any help (or steering onto a more righteous path!) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is indeed that the registration of the logger factory would occur only after the installers are done you could try the following:

Make 2 config sections castle1 castle2.

```
<castle1>        
    <facilities>
        <facility id="logging"
            type="Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility, Castle.Facilities.Logging" loggingApi="log4net" />
    </facilities>
</castle1>

<castle2>        
    <installers>
        <install type="MyProject.LoggerInstaller,MyProject" />
    </installers>
</castle2>
```

and initialize the container in 2 steps:

```
container.Install(new ConfigurationInstaller(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle1"))));
container.Install(new ConfigurationInstaller(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle2"))));
```

Also on the top of your configfile you have to specify the castle1 and castle2 section.

I've not tried it, but I think it is worth a try.

Kind regards,
Marwijn

Comment: Thank you!  I had a try of it this morning and it works perfectly!